# PayPal Execute an agreement Plan

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

Hi before i am take the EC-id form Agreement the Subscription Plan Now I am going to Executing the Plan

```
$activate_bil_execut = " http://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/EC-0TS06959WU774942K/agreement-execute";


         $header_new_execting = array(
             'Content-Type'=>'application/json',
             'Authorization'=> " Bearer $access_token",

         );

        $activate_plan_execting = '{}';


   $pay_result_exuting_ammount = wp_remote_request($activate_bil_execut, array( 'method' => 'POST', 'timeout' => 20 ,'headers' =>$header_new_execting,'body'=>$activate_plan_execting )); 

   var_export($pay_result_exuting_ammount);
```

response are here :

WP_Error::__set_state(array( 'errors' => array ( 'http_request_failed' => array ( 0 => 'Failed connect to api.paypal.com:80; Operation now in progress', ), ), 'error_data' => array ( ), ))false